# Famo.us Masonry View

Tags: angularjs, famo.us, masonry, packery

does anybody know how to archieve an masonry view inside Famo.us Angular? The delivered Grid View is pretty nice, but has no support for something like Click and Resize one Surface and align the others around it.

I´m currently building a 2 rows and multiple columns surface. On click on one Surface it should resize to the size of 2 rows and 2 columns and appending 3 other elements on his right.

I´ve tried also to include a masonry, isotope or packery div inside an famo.us surface. But it didn´t work.

Did anyone got some good advice which approach is better at the current famo.us state?

Greetings

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone built this as a proof of concept : https://github.com/naman34/famousry

it's only placing it's own generated contents in the layout, so it isn't a finished component,
but rather the start of one.

Comment: Thanks, that is at first a good starting point. Trying to figure it out how to align properly after resizing. Thank you ;)